# Zoombar slider in nokia maps [here maps]

Tags: here-api

I was looking at http://here.com/ and noticed that their controls navigation panel has a zoombar.

I was wondering if this is a map setting or is it something that needs to be custom built.

Posting it here due to lack of a better suited forum.

Answer (score 0):

A **zoombar** can be added to a map using the HERE Maps API for JavaScript as shown:

```
var map = new nokia.maps.map.Display(mapContainer, {
    // initial center and zoom level of the map
    center: [52.51, 13.4],
    zoomLevel: 10,
    components: [
        new nokia.maps.map.component.ZoomBar()
    ]
});
```

The zoombar looks like this:

[image: Normal Zoom Bar]

The zoom control on [here.com](http://here.com) looks like this:

[image]

It is a custom map control and would need to be created with your own code using the UI library of your choice and creating a new class extending `MapComponent`.

An outline sketch of how to go about this can be found in the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086514/is-it-possible-to-have-the-4-zoom-level-feature-with-ie9-and-ie10)